Webform additional settings
I have a layout builder with components on my website. Some of that components using field entity reference webform. And when CM's adding some of that components they need to have ability to decide either some handlers added or not(those handlers are added and disabled by default) to the chosen webform. I've noticed that status settings are showed when I add form to the block in node. Is there some way to add my custom 3-rd party settings to that widget(and these need to work per block so no need to export them)??
I generally can use hook_webform_handler_invoke_alter to control if there will be added needed handler or not by setting. But how to add needed setting to that widget? Is it configurable in webform? Or do I need to create custom widget?

Eventually made this ascustom widget select(to choose variants) with variants, but faced another problem is that default submission data used in first block on top of the page directly influences all others webforms references in blocks on a page. And as a result all forms with same id but different variants applied same variant that was applied first.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
